# Is there REALLY a flash to html5 converter that works?

Tags: flash, html

I have heard about smokescreen a few months ago but well yes that seems to be just that: a smoke screen I cannot see any download :)

Same for all other announcements. So is there something that is available, documented well something professional.

Comment: I tend to find converter tools never work that well, if at all. That being said my work is exploring the idea of using them.

Answer (score 2):

There are various attempts, but you have to understand that it's never going to be a 1:1 relationship. Flash Player is its own runtime, with some low-level APIs that simply allow it to do more than is possible with mere JavaScript or HTML.

That said, not everything in every Flash app makes use of everything the Flash Player can do. Right now, there are various alpha- and beta- versions of tools that are designed to take certain aspects of the Flash experience and render them using JS/HTML/CSS.

At the end of the day, even the best release of any of these will only be able to support certain elements of what's possible in Flash. If you're interested in converting your keyframe animation into JS Canvas, check out Adobe's new "Edge" plugin for Dreamweaver. If you're looking to load in AMF data from an existing back-end data-structure and tie it into a cue-point-laden video clip in a compiled, secure it against introspection and deploy it anywhere - well, no, that doesn't exist right now.

I hope that helps. :-\

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, there are things that flash can do that html5 can't, which makes such a tool impossible to make complete.

Answer (score 0):

I were using swiffy for almost year and a half and works perfectly for me, to put complex animations working with simple games and activities made in actionscript 2. I use it for e-learning courses.

I also analyzed "create JS" and traditional javascript/html5/css but it were a more complex task and i needed twice the time to do the same.

So I continue using swiffy.